# How to get elementary os to stay awake

Tags: release-loki, laptop, power, dell

I have elementary os 5.0 Loki installed on a Dell Latitude e6410. This machine will not stay awake whether it's on battery or plugged in! I will go and set the sleep time to never in power settings for both battery and plugged in and it will still just go to sleep after a while.
The one thing that is remarkable about the hardware, as far as I know, is that the laptop has a Nvidia GPU and we have had a fair amount of problems getting a proper driver for it. I'm familiar with alot of basic things in Linux but because I am not in Linux every day, there are alot of things I don't know. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's known bug:
https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/issues/89

Try this workaround:

```
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - nor other solutions I've looked for. I did a nice test last night - kept my notebook open and playing a music overnight while I kept it charging. woke up today and found that the screen was on, but black, and the sound had stopped. Not a huge deal, but annoying nonetheless.

Comment: run Commands in this order should work:

####  sudo su

enter, then your password

#### su - -s /bin/bash lightdm

enter

#### dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing

Answer (score 1):

Please run Commands in this order, It should definitely work:

> sudo su

enter, then your password

> su - -s /bin/bash lightdm

enter

> dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
>   sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing

Comment: I think that elementary may have resolved the issue. Check to see if your system is up to date. I will do a longer test. i have not tried keeping it awake over night

Comment: I don't entirely know what happened but I ran my own test last night by leaving the machine on and setting it to not sleep. This morning when I got up the screen was off but I was able to turn it on with a touch. so it seems to be fixed.